# clearRect function doesn't clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, line, draw, onmousemove

I'm using this script on the body `onmousemove` function:

```
function lineDraw() {
    // Get the context and the canvas:
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // Clear the last canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Draw the line:
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    context.stroke();
}
```

It's supposed to clear the canvas each time I move the mouse around, and draw a new line, but it isn't working properly. 
I'm trying to solve it without using jQuery, mouse listeners or similar.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0y4wf31k/

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You should use "**beginPath()**". That is it.

```
function lineDraw() {   
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width,context.height);
    context.beginPath();//ADD THIS LINE!<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    context.moveTo(0,0);
    context.lineTo(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Would like to add that this goes for draw methods such as rect and arc as well.

Comment: It's old but... `closePath` is useless and misleading here, it's just a `lineTo(previousStartingPointOfThePath)` so for a single line, it won't do anything, and it doesn't tell at all that you finished your path declaration.

Comment: Thanks @kaiido, I edited the question. I think the edit is in the spirit of the answer. Hope you don't mind aviomaksim

Comment: Thank you!  that is crazy, why does the clear fail unless you do a `beginPath`?  it makes no sense.

Answer (score 8):

Be advised that ctx.clearRect() does **not** work properly on Google Chrome. I spent hours trying to solve a related problem, only to find that on Chrome, instead of filling the rectangle with rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), it **actually** fills the rectangle with rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) instead!

Consequently, in order to have the rectangle filled *properly* with the required transparent black pixels, you need, on Chrome, to do this instead:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
```

This should, of course, work on all browsers providing proper support for the HTML5 Canvas object.

Answer (score 4):

And beginPath() and stroke() we need to use.
This code works same as clearRect(...)

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: why do we need this? what if one has a colored background?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blacked out screen using this method

```
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)"
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)    
ctx.stroke();
```

then switch all the 0's in rgba to 255

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);    
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score -4):

Try with `context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width`:

```
function lineDraw() {   
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, context.width,context.height);
    context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;
    context.moveTo(0,0);
    context.lineTo(event.clientX,event.clientY);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/7vx2z/3/)

Comment: or simply `myCanvas.width = myCanvas.width;`.