# Canvas Clear not working; Array items dont get deleted

Tags: javascript

The squares still get drawn even tough they are deleted from the array that is drawn. Shouldn't they be deleted when they are being deleted from the Array. Does the array not update inside the go function?

Javascript:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#thebutton").on('click',function(){
        thearray.pop();
    })
    canvas = $('#canvas').get(0);
    ctx =canvas.getContext("2d");
})

class Square{
    constructor(p1,p2,p3,p4){
        this.p1=p1;
        this.p2=p2;
        this.p3=p3;
        this.p4=p4;
    }
    start(){
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.go();
            that.start();
            console.log("timeout running");

        },1000);
    }
    go(){

       for(let i = 0; i<thearray.length;i++){
           console.log("loop running:"+i);
            if(true){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
                console.log("clearing rect");
            }
            ctx.rect(thearray[i].p1, thearray[i].p2, thearray[i].p3, thearray[i].p4);
            ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
}

var thearray=[];
var thesquare1 = new Square(20,20,150,100);
var thesquare2 = new Square(100,100,200,200);
var thesquare3 = new Square(200,200,300,300);
thearray.push(thesquare1);
thearray.push(thesquare2);
thearray.push(thesquare3);

thesquare1.start();
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
<button type="button" name="button" id="thebutton">Pop Array</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent almost an hour on debugging your code!
This led to the finding that if `fillRect()` is used instead of `rect()` the code works well...
and then finally found this..
(I too didn't know it before ><)
Have a look at this: [link](http://codetheory.in/why-clearrect-might-not-be-clearing-canvas-pixels/)

---

In short, just call `beginPath()` after `clearRect()` to start a new path instead of using old path stack!!!

```
go(){

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
   ctx.beginPath(); //This line saved the day :)))
   console.log("clearing rect");

   for(let i = 0; i<thearray.length;i++) {
       console.log("loop running:"+i);
        ctx.rect(thearray[i].p1, thearray[i].p2, thearray[i].p3, thearray[i].p4);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

using this the code works for `rect()` as intended :)

**Note:** also you have to move that `clearRect()` call outside the for loop otherwise it will clear the canvas after every single iteration of the loop which results in showing only the 3rd rectangle on the canvas.
Also, that `if(true){}` is not at all necessary.

**Update:** Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435959/clearrect-function-doesnt-clear-the-canvas) thread for some other alternatives to `beginPath()` to handle such scenario

Comment: Thats the solution. It took me a long time too! Thank you very much!!